# How to use processbuilder to run piped processes in windows

Tags: java, pipe

processbuilder does not allow redirecting inputstream/output streams. How can I create piped processes in java?
I tried to use this command but it doesn't work.

```
process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd","sort < randomwords.txt | sort /R >reversesortes.txt");
```

EDIT: Still this is not working.

```
ArrayList<String> cmd = new ArrayList<>(); 
String s = "/R"; 
cmd.add("cmd"); 
cmd.add("sort"); 
cmd.add("<"); 
cmd.add("randomwords.txt"); 
cmd.add("|"); 
cmd.add("sort"); 
cmd.add("/R"); 
cmd.add( ">"); 
cmd.add("reversesortes.txt"); 
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(cmd); 
builder.redirectError(new File("error.txt")); 
Process process = builder.start(); 
System.out.println("im here" ); 
int i = process.waitFor(); 
System.out.println("i"+ i );
```

Comment: I would place all the tokens, including the `"<"` and the `"|"` into an `ArrayList<String>` and use that with ProcessBuilder to create my process.

Comment: In other words, your exec currently holds two Strings, and instead it should probably be comprised of 9 distinct tokens.

Comment: Still this is not working.  ArrayList<String> cmd = new ArrayList<>();
  String s = "/R";
     cmd.add("cmd");
     cmd.add("sort");
     cmd.add("<"); 
     cmd.add("randomwords.txt");
     cmd.add("|");
     cmd.add("sort");
     cmd.add("/R");
     cmd.add( ">");
     cmd.add("reversesortes.txt");
     ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(cmd);
  builder.redirectError(new File("error.txt"));

  Process process = builder.start();
  System.out.println("im here" );
  int i = process.waitFor();
  
  System.out.println("i"+ i );

Comment: Input file specified two times error.

Answer (score 2):

As the name of the shell is `cmd`, I assume that your OS is Windows. `cmd.exe` requires a `/c` to introduce a command passed as parameter. In an interactive shell, this command:

```
C:\Users\sj>cmd echo foo
Microsoft Windows [version 6.0.6002]
Copyright (c) 2006 Microsoft Corporation. Tous droits réservés.

C:\Users\sj>
```

only opens a new interactive shell waiting for commands on its standard input whereas

```
C:\Users\sj>cmd /c echo foo
foo

C:\Users\sj>
```

correctly executes the command passed as parameter.

So you should write:

```
ArrayList<String> cmd = new ArrayList<>(); 
cmd.add("cmd"); 
cmd.add("/C"); 
cmd.add("sort < randomwords.txt | sort /R >reversesortes.txt"); 
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(cmd); 
builder.redirectError(new File("error.txt")); 
Process process = builder.start();
```